# What are the valid names as labels?

Tags: cross-referencing, symbols, characters, naming

What are the valid characters to use in labels? I thought that only alphabetic characters were valid, but I tested `'` and `!` and they work. What are the restrictions to these names?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

ASCII characters in the 32-127 range that are not special for TeX are acceptable, including punctuation characters; *don't use accented characters when the package `inputenc` is loaded*.  Sticking to letters, numbers, hyphen, colon, and perhaps `&` seems the best.  Spaces are also allowed, but not recommended, mostly because editors might break lines at them.

Some of the special characters can be employed: `&`, `_`, `^`, but not `%`, `~`, `#`, and `\`. Even `{` and `}` might be used, as long as they are properly balanced. However this is not recommended practice. The underscore and `&` may be useful delimiters for giving structure to the labels; often the colon is used for this.

**Warning.** Some characters might give problems when babel is loaded along with varioref (for example the colon `:` with French and the double quote `"` with many languages). Without varioref these should be OK. As Martin points out, some packages might redefine `_`, making it unusable in labels.

Comment: I disagree on `#` and `~`. Both generate errors for me. `#` can't be used in macro definitions done internally by `\label` and `~` can expand to `\nobreakspace {}` which will break when written to the `.aux` file. Also some people like to redefine `_` which would also break if it is defined fragile. I would avoid all characters special to TeX and also all non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Excelent, that gives a lot of options to my automatic system generator. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinScharrer do you think that using all the letters and punctuation characters is perfectly safe?

Comment: @Martin: right, I presumed that the protection mechanism covered also `~` and `#`.

Comment: @voodoomsr: It depends on your used packages. Some languages supported by the `babel` package defines different punctuation marks to be active. Then they might cause trouble. In my quick test `"` still seems to work in `\label`s after `[german]{babel}` defined it active. You should stick to a sane selections of character anyway. I'm using only letters, numbers and `:`, `-`, `_` and never had any issues or needed more characters.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, @egreg thanks both for the explanations.

Comment: The important point here, though, is that spaces *are* allowed.  This can be very helpful in formulating non-cryptic label names.

Comment: @MartinScharrer So it is correct that using `-` at the end of a label or using `--` within a label is okay too? Just checking, as I am not familiar with (La)TeX's parsing internals and thus don't know how LaTeX processes en-dashes internally.

Comment: @user14996 Yes, there's no problem in using them; `--` is transformed into an en dash at a deeper level, at printing time, not when tokens are formed.

Comment: By saying "ASCII character that are not special for TeX are acceptable," you just beg the following question: which ascii characters are special for TeX?  Can numbers be used in variable names?  This is an important question, and deserves an exhaustive answer.  Please give a full overview of valid variable names.

Comment: @conradlee By ASCII I mean the printable ones below 128, that is in the range `32-127`. Some of them are disallowed, as I said in my answer; others are not recommended. Sticking to letters, numbers, hyphen, and perhaps `&` seems the best. The underscore *may* be risky if the `underscore` package is loaded. Accented characters are definitely out of the question, unless you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.