# How to add a caption below a picture in Latex? I don't know why its not working. I attached my text below

Tags: captions, diagrams

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    pointlessnumbers, 
    %draft,
    parskip=half,
    automark
        ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref}


    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\! \, \cdot \! \,}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{SC Bilder/sc1.png} 
\label{fig:Veranschaulichung Erzeugung von polarisiertem Licht}
\end{center}
\caption{Veranschaulichung der Erzeugung von linear polarisierten Lichgt und zirkular polarisiertem Licht}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason is probably that you are not using a ‘figure’ environment. Use that instead of ‘center’ and place the caption command inside of it.

Comment: Unrelated: your preamble is quite a mess. Some packages are loaded several times, such as siunitx which even has different options, and some are redundant, such as loading ‘color’ when you also load xcolor. Also, hyperref should generally be the last in the list. And so on.

Comment: The `subfigure` package is considered obsolete. You may want to use `subcaption` or `subfig` instead.

Comment: As far as I can remebmer `decimalsymbol` which you added to the options of `siunitx` was an option used in version 1 (prior to 2010) of the package. Similarly, `scrpage2` is considered obsolete since 2015 and the package author recommends using ` scrlayer-scrpage` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by making your code more minimal:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image} 
\label{fig:Veranschaulichung Erzeugung von polarisiertem Licht}
\end{center}
\caption{Veranschaulichung der Erzeugung von linear polarisierten Lichgt und zirkular polarisiertem Licht}

\end{document}
```

If you compile this code, you end up with the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.
```

You get this error message, since you can only use the `\caption` command inside of a floating environment such as `figure` or `table`.

So let' s replace `center` with `figure` and move the `caption` command inside of the `\figure` environment. For correct cross-referencing, make sure the `\label`is placed *after*  the corresponding `\caption`. In the following MWE, I also added `\centering` in order to horizontally center the image:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
\caption{Veranschaulichung der Erzeugung von linear polarisierten Licht und zirkular polarisiertem Licht} 
\label{fig:Veranschaulichung Erzeugung von polarisiertem Licht}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For some background information on floats and how you can control their placement, take a look a the following questions and their answers.

[How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144)

[Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/134144)

If you absolutely don't want your image to move away from where it was mentioned in the code, you could use the following approach based on the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package. However, please be aware that large white spaces can occur in your document, especially if an image is too large for the remaining space on a page:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{Veranschaulichung der Erzeugung von linear polarisierten Licht und zirkular polarisiertem Licht} 
\label{fig:Veranschaulichung Erzeugung von polarisiertem Licht}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

A final remark on the `\label` command: Although spaces are allowed in a lable, I would recommend not using them. Personally, I'd also use a shorter, but still descriptive key, for example something like `\label{fig:Erzg-pol-Licht}`. Some background on allowed characters inside of a `\label` can be found here:
[What are the valid names as labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18311/134144)

Comment: Thank you so so much Sir! It really helped me!!! Have a great day!