# Allowing \label to contain \&

Tags: labels

relates to [What are the valid names as labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18311/what-are-the-valid-names-as-labels) .

```
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}\label{KW:#1}\pageref{KW:#1}}
```

works just great for almost any text...until one wants `\keyword{S\&P~500}`.  The problem is that label does not allow a `\` to be part of the label, but it is the only way to typeset the `&` character in the text.  Is there an `\xlabel` command that is a little more forgiving, i.e., first stripping or mangling any invalid characters from #1, after expanding it once of course?  (I tried changing the catcode of either `&` or `\\` in the macro, but couldn't figure it out.  I can't assign to a variable and include it for the same reason that it would contain a `\` again.)

Comment: `&` is valid in a `\label`; on the contrary, control sequences should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this use `&` not `\&` so

```
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{\detokenize{#1}}\label{KW:#1}\pageref{KW:#1}}
```

and

```
\keyword{S&P 500}
```